# How to arrange svg elements on top of other div?

Tags: html, css, svg

I am trying to arrange this small SVG rectangle on top of the base rectangle present in the same SVG viewBox and on top the other div which is just below it.

Any help would be appreciated.

**Edit 1**
I want rect with id="over" top of div with class="firstrect" and div with class="secondrect".

[image: Screenshot]

```css
.main {
  position: relative;
}

.secondrect {
  width: 100%;
  background: purple;
  height: 30px;
}

#over {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="firstrect">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 50 10">
          <rect width="100%" height="100%" style="fill: rgb(102, 102, 201);" />
          <rect
            id="over"
            x="10"
            y="9"
            width="20%"
            height="20%"
            style="fill: rgb(102, 201, 171);"
          />
        </svg>
  </div>
  <div class="secondrect"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set `svg` `overflow: visible;`

```css
svg {
  overflow: visible;
}

.secondrect {
  width: 100%;
  background: purple;
  height: 30px;
}

#over {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="firstrect">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 50 10">
          <rect width="100%" height="100%" style="fill: rgb(102, 102, 201);" />
          <rect
            id="over"
            x="10"
            y="9"
            width="20%"
            height="20%"
            style="fill: rgb(102, 201, 171);"
          />
        </svg>
  </div>
  <div class="secondrect"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Add **class="viewbox"** to the viewbox.
2. Then, add ***overflow: visible*** on said class
3. Then adjust x and y coordinates as you see fit

```css
.main {
  position: relative;
}
/*Add class="viewbox" to viewbox */
.viewbox {
 overflow: visible;
}

.secondrect {
  width: 100%;
  background: purple;
  height: 30px;
}

#over {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="firstrect">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 50 10" class="viewbox">
          <rect width="100%" height="100%" style="fill: rgb(102, 102, 201);" />
          <rect
            id="over"
            x="10"
            y="9"
            width="20%"
            height="30%"
            style="fill: rgb(152, 251, 071);"
          />
        </svg>
  </div>
  <div class="secondrect"></div>
</div>
```